# Can't reach some registry subkeys

Tags: c#, registry

I need to reach to all subkeys of this registry key:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\

There are 12 subkeys of this reg key. But when I try to reach those subkeys, the code returns only 3 subkeys.

I need to reach the subkey "InstallRoot":

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\InstallRoot

But the code returns null.

My code is as follows:

```
RegistryKey key = 
      Registry.LocalMachine
              .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\InstallRoot");
```

.NET Framework version is 2.0 and my OS is Win7 x64, my app is x86.

Comment: Provide us with your code

Comment: I am guessing you don't have permission to those subkeys. When does your code return null? What is your code, for that matter.

Comment: Can you check the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office location using regedit and see if it contains the 3 subkeys in question?

Comment: When I Open "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\" it is ok. But when I add "InstallRoot" it returns null. Doesnt find the subkey. And when I get all subkeys with the function "GetSubKeyNames", it return 3 subkeys of 12.

Comment: yes zaitsman, you are right.
But I dont indicate Wow6432 in the reg path. How is it possible?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I followed up Hans's links and found a good solution here:

http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa

Thank you all